# Definition of semi-ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I need the definition of [semi-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Definition) homomorphism. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition should depend on your purposes, but I think that this should be the best definition:

$$f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$$
$$f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$$
$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f(1) = 1$$

Unlike with rings, you cannot deduce $f(0) = 0$ from the other axioms.

If you want to work with non-unital semirings, you might drop the last axiom.  But as far as I can tell, semirings are always defined to be additive monoids, in which case you definitely should not drop $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Soviet You're quite welcome. :)

Comment: if $\forall a,b \in A(a \preceq b \to f(a) \preceq f(b))$ then $f$ is order semi-ring homomorphism, is correct?

Comment: @Soviet Sure, why not?  If you have some algebraic relations and operations, a morphism should be anything that preserves all of them.  You just have to be careful to include everything (such as, in my answer, constant symbols).

Answer (score 3):

For any sort of algebra, a homomorphism is a function that preserves the structure.

What do you consider to be the structure of a semiring? $0,1,+,\cdot$? Then the definition of homomorphism is any function $R \to S$ such that

- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(1) = 1$
- $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$
- $f(a \cdot b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$

The same is true for fields, groups, or whatever.

Aside: the definition of group homomorphism is usually presented in a different way. But it turns out that any function between groups that preserves $\cdot$ also preserves ${}^{-1}$ and $1$, so the above general notion also works in the group case.

Another aside: this is part of why people make a big deal about whether the existence of a multiplicative identity in a ring is specified by giving a constant $1$ that satisfies $\forall x: 1x=x1=x$, or by an existential statement like $\exists e \forall x: ex = xe = x$. The two different options lead to two different notions of ring homomorphism.

Comment: Does it entail that any homomorphism $h$ from $(N_{0},0,1,+,.)$ to itself is the restriction to this semiring of a field automorphism?

Answer (score -1):

Just as for rings: $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b), f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.

Comment: ah.. thanks :)!!

Comment: Can you deduce $f(0) = 0$ from these?  This should be a requirement.

Comment: @user33433, mmm $f(0_A)=f(0_A+0_A)=f(0_A)+f(0_A)=f(0_A)+0_B \to f(0_A)=0_B$, $\to$ is possibile because $A$ is monoid..

Comment: @Soviet You are assuming cancellation.  It might not be true that $a+b = a+c \implies b=c$.

Comment: @user33433, true.. sorry... :(

Comment: @user33433 Yes, one has to add $f(0)=0$