# About definition of "ordered semi-ring"

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I need the definition of "ordered [semi-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Definition)". Can I use [these properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring):

$a \preceq b \to a + c \preceq b + c$

$0 \preceq a \wedge 0 ≤ b \to 0 \preceq a \cdot b$   (or: $a \preceq b \wedge 0 \preceq c \to a \cdot c \preceq b \cdot c $)

???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found three slightly different definitions of *ordered semiring*. This one may be the oldest:

> **Definition:** A semiring $R$ is *ordered* if there is a partial order $\preceq$ on $R$ such that
>
> 1. $a+c\preceq b+c$ whenever $a,b,c\in R$ and $a\preceq b$, and
> 2. $ac\preceq bc$ and $ca\preceq cb$ whenever $a,b,c\in R$, $0\preceq c$, and $a\preceq b$.
>
> $R$ is *positive* if $0\preceq a$ for all $a\in R$.

Another definition removes the restriction that $0\preceq c$ from (2); the two are clearly equivalent for positive ordered semirings. The third adds to the second the requirement that $0\preceq a$ for all $a\in R$, so it’s equivalent to the notion of positive ordered semiring in either of the first two senses of *ordered semiring*.

All of these definitions explicitly include additive monotonicity, your first property. Your second property follows from (2) above, so it holds no matter which of these definitions is in use: if $0\preceq a$ and $0\preceq b$, then $0=0\cdot b\preceq a\cdot b$. Thus, under any of these definitions of *ordered ring* you can use both of the properties that you listed.

Comment: M.Scott, can be deduced $ca \preceq cb$ from $ac \preceq bc$?.. thanks soo much in advance! :)

Comment: @Soviet: Multiplication in a semiring need not be commutative; if you’re working in a semiring in which it *is* commutative, then of course each of those inequalities implies the other, but if your multiplication is not commutative, they don’t imply each other.

Comment: let be $(A,+_A,\cdot_A)$ and $(B,+_B, \cdot_B)$ are ordered semirings, $f: A \to B$ semiring homomorphism (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539087/definition-of-semi-ring-homomorphism), if $\forall a,b \in A (a \preceq b \to f(a) \preceq f(b))$ then $f$ is order semiring homomorphism, is correct?

Comment: @Soviet: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: M.Scott.. thanks very much! :)

Comment: @Soviet: You’re very welcome!