# What does the kernel of a semiring homomorphism being a null set signify?

Tags: ring-homomorphism, semiring

According to [wikipedia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)&ved=2ahUKEwiY9syTn_DlAhXbinAKHe0kDOwQFjAHegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw188_I57OwTCax27Vh_d1mu), the kernel of a homomorphism measures the degree to which a homomorphism fails to be injective.

> What does it mean when a kernel of semiring is a null set? That is when $f:S\longrightarrow S'$ is a homomorphism between semirings $S$ and $S'$ such that $ker(f)=\lbrace \rbrace$, a null set. Is it true that a homomorphism whose kernel is a null set always a one-one mapping?

Comment: the article you linked says that the kernel of a homomorphism is trivial if and only if the homomorphism is injective.

Comment: If we are using [the definition given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539087/definition-of-semi-ring-homomorphism) then the kernel always contains the zero element so it cannot be empty.

Comment: @Brian Moehring i have in mind that sort of definition, but at the same time i am getting the kernal as an empty set in a counter example, which is a difficult to be explained here in detail

Comment: If your definition matches what is given in the link and your map $f$ has $f^{-1}(0)=\emptyset$, then the conclusion would be that $f$ isn't a semiring homomorphism.